# PHP Form Processing with only filled in fields

Tags: php

I have a PHP class which have 8 properties
and a HTML form which have 40 (8*5) textboxes, 8 per object, so a user can enter data for 5 objects at once.

For each set of boxes I want to create an object of the class and save it into my database. If the user for example have filled in 10 boxes (two sets), two objects should be created and saved.

Comment: So what's your question? [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Are you not putting some checks on your form which determines how many fields are filled...Also, why so many fields. Show just 5 fields initially and give a "Add another user" button, which creates 5 more fields when clicked. That will allow you a better control.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, here is HTML form example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="groups[0][first_name]" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="groups[0][last_name]" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="groups[1][first_name]" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="groups[1][last_name]" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 3</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="groups[2][first_name]" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="groups[2][last_name]" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Pay attention to field names, how fields are grupped. After submitting form like this, your $_POST superglobal array will contain $_POST['groups'] array of following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
        )

)
```

You can easily process such data with code like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['groups'] as $group) {
  $group = array_filter($group);

  if (!empty($group)) {
    // do something with group
  }
}
```

This little example loops through all submitted groups. array_filter() function will throw away all empty values from each $group array, and !empty(...) will make sure that $group is not empty.